# MongoDB returns results when it should not

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am searching arrays in a collection and Mongodb (Mongoose) returns an empty array even though I know it shouldn't find the URL path I have submitted.

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {

var path = req.url;

db.find({arrayOfPaths:path})
 .then(function(db){

  console.log(db);

  //db returns empty array why?

  res.status(200).render('results', {db});
  })

  .catch()

})
```

Comment: Because that is what mongoose does. The result of `.find()` is **always** an array. Empty or not. No results therefore is an array with no entries.

Comment: Thanks so much. Cleared that up. :)